# Center div container, scrollbar appears

Tags: html, css, margin

I have following html site structure:

```
  <body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="container">    
        <div id="util_header"></div>
        <div id="contentwrapper" class="frontpage">Content</div>
    </div>
  </body>
```

Now I want to center the #container. The works when I apply following css:

```
#container {
    width: 960px;
    margin: auto;
    background:red;
}

#util_header{
    width: 100%; height:32px;
    position: relative;
    background:url('../images/logo.png') no-repeat #eeeeee;
    border-top:1px solid #b6bac0;
}

#header {
    width: 100%; height:32px;
    position: absolute;
    background:#eeeeee;
    border-top:1px solid #b6bac0;
}

#contentwrapper {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    background:red;
}
```

The `magin: auto;` centers the container. My problem is that I need the container to be larger, but when I increase width from 960 to 980 I get a vertical scrollbar. I played around with the css but got no clue how to manage that problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: You should read a bit on Vertical Centering (I wish it were that simple): http://blog.themeforest.net/tutorials/vertical-centering-with-css/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ArtWorkAD,

CSS3 introduced the Flexible box model, maybe you can use it depending the audience of your website...

So to Vertically & Horizontally center block Level elements in the body element, you'd just have to write this CSS declaration:

```
body {
  display: box;
  box-orient: horizontal;
  /* horizontally centered */
  box-pack: center;
  /* vertically centered */
  box-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  height : 100%;
}
```

http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/04/the-css-3-flexible-box-model/

*edit*

To have wide browser support, you can always rely on CSS hacks and do some negative margin trickery as seen on http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html
 ;)

Oh and if you don't want a scrollbar at all, make sure you have put an overflow:hidden on the body element.

Comment: *cries*. Now that CSS3 has completely amazed me, how am I to deal with developing for IE users too? It barely supports CSS2, and IE users are *still* transitioning to IE7/IE8. *sobs*

Comment: @Blender, we just have to hope that MSFT will be ready to support the full CSS3 spec with IE9, but seriously I doubt it...

Comment: I hope some web developer/hacker creates a rampaging internet worm that installs Chrome 9 Dev (or FF4 for the faint of heart) on every Windows machine it gets into. I would donate money to such a project (anonymously :P).